# I am trying to install requirements, but it is not picking up values from pip.conf file

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04, wsl-2

I have **wsl2** in my windows with **ubuntu 18.04**.
I have to pick few variables from pip.conf file while installing the requirements in my virtual environment. I have kept this file in **~/.config/pip/pip.conf** location.

While my project is in **/mnt/f/**  location.

Any idea why it is not detecting the variables?

Comment: Try moving it to `~/.pip/pip.conf`. Aside from that, you can use the `PIP_CONFIG_FILE=path/to/pip.conf` env var.

Comment: @hoefling Tried these as well. Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started working after

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Apparently, the pip version required is **20.1.1**